# C# webbrowser - Получить позиции элементов html

Tags: c#, html, webbrowser, c++

Есть `html` файл на диске. 
После загрузки в `webbrowser.loadfromfile` как можно получить реальные позиции элементов на экране в данный момент? например тегов `<p>`

Что проще `webkit` или встроенный в винду `iexplorer`?

Comment: Что ж за день сегодня такой? Вы знаете что такое **webkit**? И что значит "*загрузить в броузер и спросить его*"? Не думаю, что браузеры научились отвечать. А если ближе к теме, то узнать позиции элементов страницы, можно с использованием JS. Но боюсь, что эта область вам мало знакома.

Comment: попробуйте phantom.

Comment: Если под webkit имелась в виду layout engine, то можно теоретически подключить её к утилите командной строки, скормить ей html, и пройтись по атрибутам полученного DOM-дерева. Не уверен, имел ли ТС именно это в виду.

Comment: пример нужен прохода итератором по htmlelement-ам  и подозреваю в свойствах у них есть позиция, но позиция относительная вроде(
через webkit не знаю как там устроено наверное аналогично

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Щелчок правой кнопкой на элементе, и далее:
Исследовать элемент - chrome, firefox
проинспектировать элемент - opera

Comment: согласен. можно еще  Javascript с JQuery использовать, если программно